# Akeneo ElasticSearch - bytes can be at most 32766 in length

Tags: elasticsearch, akeneo

Im using Akeneo 2.2.4 an receive the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"values.assets_variation-textarea.ecommerce.de_DE.preprocessed\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[123, 34, 104, 97, 117, 112, 116, 97, 110, 115, 105, 99, 104, 116, 34, 58, 91, 123, 34, 113, 117, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121, 34, 58, 34, 119]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 37878"
            }
        ],
    "status": 400
}
```

Is there a way to overwrite the configuration for elastic? Something like: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html

Or any other solutions/practices?

Comment: We fixed a similar issue some weeks ago: https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/pull/8045 . Is your issue related to textarea too?

Comment: Sorry, im late. Yes its related to textareas. But i had no chance to test your feature, because we changed the data handling and the exception solved by itself.